# JavaFX Thread locking system

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, thread-safety

I have a Main Stage which is my login
FXML in this stage have a Region and a ProgressIndicator with property setVisible (false)

After successfully logging into the application the intention would be the following view this Region and the ProgressIndicator while a thread started the application, but what happens is that after logging the thread starts rotating loading the application, but the Region and the ProgressIndicator, are not visible.

**My Thread**

```
Task t = new Task() {

    @Override
    protected Object call() throws Exception {

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            try {

                new SisgeFX().start();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
};
region.visibleProperty().bind(t.runningProperty());
pi.visibleProperty().bind(t.runningProperty());
Thread th = new Thread(t);
th.start();
```

I tried making two threads one to boot the system and another to update the `ProgressIndicator` while the system is not loaded, but without success, does not generate `Excepetion`, already tried in several ways.

**What I realized in my several attempts:**

1 - A Thread and started and the other not (Starts only the thread that loads the system).

2 - Thread not start.

3 - the Tread starts but ProgressIndicator is locked, it is not animanda.

Excerpt login:

```
 @FXML
    private void sysLogin() {
    String user = ctfUserLogin.getText();
    String pass = ctfPassLogin.getText();
    LoginDAO loginDAO = DAOFactory.make(LoginDAO.class);
    Login login = loginDAO.getLogin(user, pass);

    if (login != null) {
        runThread(); // aqui chamo a Thread postado acima.
        ctfPassLogin.setStyle(null);
        ctfUserLogin.setStyle(null);
    } else {
        ctfPassLogin.clear();
        ctfUserLogin.clear();
        ctfPassLogin.setStyle("-fx-border-color:red;");
        ctfUserLogin.setStyle("-fx-border-color:red;");
        //new ShakeTransition(vBox).play();
        new WobbleTransition(vBox).play();
        //new TadaTransition(vBox).play();
    }

}
```

How to Displaying the ProgressIndicator while the system is loaded?

Comment: There exists a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27090426/progressbar-in-javafx-does-not-update-in-onaction-block/27092945#27092945 . perhaps that helps....

Comment: Thanks, but don't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of method, Try below statement.

```
Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
```